# i cant figure out why the message and senderId is not recognised in the code

Tags: android, kotlin

the problem is that the message and senderId is not recognised even tho i have a custom message class i asked chatgpt he said to remove import android.view.textclassifier.ConversationActions and that didn’t fix the issue please help me with this issue

```
class MessageAdapter(val context: Context,val messageList: ArrayList<ConversationActions.Message>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){

    val ITEM_RECEIVE = 1
    val ITEM_SENT = 2

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        if (viewType == 1){
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.receive, parent, false)
            return ReceiveViewHolder(view)
        }else{
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.send, parent, false)
            return SentViewHolder(view)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messageList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentMessage = messageList[position]

        if (holder.javaClass == SentViewHolder::class.java){

            val viewHolder = holder as SentViewHolder
            holder.sentMessage.text = currentMessage.message

        }else {

            val viewHolder =  holder as ReceiveViewHolder
            holder.receiveMessage.text = currentMessage.message

        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

        val currentMessage = messageList[position]

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.equals(currentMessage.senderId)){
            return ITEM_SENT
        }else{
            return ITEM_RECEIVE
        }
    }

    class SentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val sentMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_send_message)
    }

    class ReceiveViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val receiveMessage = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_receive_message)

    }


}
```